# Microsoft Configuration Manager Server Sharing

Tags: windows, sql, sccm, configuration-management, microsoft

I have my SCCM Server connected to the SQL Server via ESXI through two different VM's. I have Microsoft Configuration Manager on my SCCM trying to get it connected to the SQL Server. How do I connect Microsoft Configuration Manager to the SQL Server if I am running SCCM and SQL on separate VM's?

Answer (score 0):

Configuration Manager requires that you configure your SQL Server instance and Configuration Manager site database (if already present) to use the SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS collation

And then create a database, in this howto there is also a reference to a script to create the database.
https://www.systemcenterdudes.com/complete-sccm-installation-guide-and-configuration/

When you run the setup wizard, at a certain step if you follow the wizard, you have an option to specify the sql server.